# How to make objects position start from Bottom Left corner

Tags: actionscript-3

So Im having trouble figuring this out.
Im trying to make the stage.y and stage.y at the bottom right corner of the stage, so whenever I add a like this

```
        box.x = 100
        box.y = 100
        this.addChild(box);
```

it would be 100px from the bottom left corner of the stage.

i tried with

```
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.BOTTOM_LEFT;
```

but it did`nt work.
Am I missing something?

Comment: hrm, I could be wrong, but I'm not so sure that the align property is meant to be used this way...

Comment: hmmm ok, i was thinking the same after a session of tries, yet is there a way to do what i want ?

Comment: StageAlign.BOTTOM_LEFT property is not for the positioning of display objects in stage wrt to bottom left. Its for the positioning of the display objects when the entire flash window resizes, i.e, when stage resizes these display objects will stick to bottom left. The x/y positioning will always be from top-left in any case.

Comment: so there is no way of doing this without making a moviecclip and making its Registration point at bottom left ? and adding the things in this movie clip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment of "making a moviecclip and making its Registration point at bottom left ? and adding the things in this movie clip" is certainly one way to do it. Probably the easiest an first method that comes to mind and lets you move it around easily on demand and have any contained objects update.

Another method would be to create a point object and reference that to position everything. Something like:

```
var origin:Point = new Point(0, this.stage.stageHeight);
```

and then for your box:

```
box.x = origin.x + 100;
box.y = origin.y - 100;
```

However, if you want to change this, you'll have to add some code that goes and updates all the positions of your existing objects.

---

If you're really insisting on that +y goes upwards and -y going downwards on the stage, you could use a trick, but there may be a hefty overhead mental cost:

Use the first method, but give the movieclip a negative 100 y scaling before positioning at the lower left corner Note that everything will now be upside down though so you'll have to handle/factor that side effect in. Not recommended, but just throwing that out there.

Comment: ill probable do the **Point** thing , it seems easy and clear. 10x

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a static method and call it always when you need, example:

```
public class DisplayObjectUtils
{
    public static function setRegPoint(obj:DisplayObjectContainer, newX:Number, newY:Number):void
    {
        var bounds:Rectangle = obj.getBounds(obj.parent);
        var currentRegX:Number = obj.x - bounds.left;
        var currentRegY:Number = obj.y - bounds.top;

        var xOffset:Number = newX - currentRegX;
        var yOffset:Number = newY - currentRegY;

        obj.x += xOffset;
        obj.y += yOffset;

        var totalChildren:uint = obj.numChildren;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < totalChildren; i++)
        {
            obj.getChildAt(i).x -= xOffset;
            obj.getChildAt(i).y -= yOffset;
        }
        bounds = null;
    }
}
```

And to use, try something like:

```
//register point in the center of the object //box.width >> 1, box.height >> 1
DisplayObjectUtils.setRegPoint(box, box.width >> 1, box.height >> 1);
```